# How do I add existing completions to a new function in zsh?

Tags: homebrew, zsh

I have a zsh function that essentially aliases a docker-machine command, how do I hook completions into this function that completes the machine names?

```
dme() {
    eval $(docker-machine env ${1})
}
```

When I do compdef dme=docker-machine it completes the commands not the machines. I'm using the _docker-machine completions that got installed with homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`compdef _docker-machine dme`

if you're using an actual alias, zsh would probably complete it correctly...

Comment: Sadly it gives me the docker-machine options when I do that rather than my machine names.

Comment: inspect `_docker_machine` code and figure how to ask it for the machine names? You can always do `compdef '_docker-machine opt1 opt2' dme`